# How to find closest embedding vectors?

Tags: deep-learning, embedding, word-embedding, vector-database

I have 100K known embedding i.e.

```
[emb_1, emb_2, ..., emb_100000]
```

Each of this embedding is derived from GPT-3 sentence embedding with dimension 2048.

My task is given an embedding(`embedding_new`) find the closest 10 embedding from the above `100k` embedding.

The way I am approaching this problem is brute force.

Every time a query asks to find the closest embeddings, I compare `embedding_new` with `[emb_1, emb_2, ..., emb_100000]` and get the similarity score.

Then I do quicksort of the similarity score to get the top `10` closest embedding.

Alternatively, I have also thought about using Faiss.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: what do you use for similarity? what is the word dimension? if each similarity is O(d), then your algorithm already runs in O(d n log n). you can reduce the log n factor using heapselect but anything further may or may not be possible with k-d trees, depending on distribution and similarity measure. by curse of dimensionality, you likely need much more than 2^d points for a k-d tree to be successful

Comment: also look up locality sensitive hashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using Vector Database Lite (VDBLITE)

VDBLITE here: https://pypi.org/project/vdblite/

```
import vdblite
from time import time
from uuid import uuid4
import sys
from pprint import pprint as pp


if __name__ == '__main__':
    vdb = vdblite.Vdb()
    dimension = 12    # dimensions of each vector                         
    n = 200    # number of vectors                   
    np.random.seed(1)             
    db_vectors = np.random.random((n, dimension)).astype('float32')
    print(db_vectors[0])
    for vector in db_vectors:
        info = {'vector': vector, 'time': time(), 'uuid': str(uuid4())}
        vdb.add(info)
    vdb.details()
    results = vdb.search(db_vectors[10])
    pp(results)
```

Looks like it uses FAISS behind the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Using you own idea, just make sure that the embeddings are in a matrix form, you can easily use `numpy` for this.
This is computed in linear time (in num. of embeddings) and should be fast.

> ```
> import numpy as np
> k = 10 # k best embeddings
> emb_mat = np.stack([emb_1, emb_2, ..., emb_100000])
> scores = np.dot(emb_mat, embedding_new)
> best_k_ind = np.argpartition(scores, k)[-k:] 
> top_k_emb = emb_mat[best_k_ind]
> ```

The 10 best embeddings will be found in `top_k_emb`.
For a general solution inside a software project you might consider [Faiss](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss) by Facebook Research.
An example for using Faiss:

> ```
> d = 2048  # dimensionality of your embedding data
> k = 10  # number of nearest neighbors to return
> index = faiss.IndexFlatIP(d)
> emb_list = [emb_1, emb_2, ..., emb_100000]
> index.add(emb_list)
> D, I = index.search(embedding_new, k)
> ```

You can use `IndexFlatIP` for inner product similarity, or `indexFlatL2` for Euclidian\L2-norm distance.
In order to bypass memory issues (data>1M) refer to this great infographic [Faiss cheat sheet](https://wangzwhu.github.io/home/file/acmmm-t-part3-ann.pdf) at slide num. 7